Correlation between diffusion coefficient and ligand–receptor binding?
A cell may have different types of cellular receptor for different molecules. Furthermore, the same cellular receptor may bind many different molecules (competitive ligand binding). My question is:
a) Is there any kind physical factor shared by ligands that bind to the same receptor?
More specifically, are the diffusion coefficient similar to one another in such cases?
b) Are there cases where different molecules binding to the same or different receptors on the same cell have similar diffusion coefficients?

Why the focus on diffusion coefficient?
